# What event is fired when a Discord bot joins a guild?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js to create a basic Discord bot. When the bot is first started, I run `client.guilds.array()` to get a list of all guilds that the bot is currently subscribed to. I save this to a database that's used by other programs.

However, as people add / remove the bot from their guilds, I'd like to keep an updated list of guilds. I realize I could just re-run `clients.guilds.array()` every minute or something, but that seems inefficient.

Is there an event that fires when your bot is added to a guild and/or channel? From what I've read, the `guildMemberAdd` event seems to fire for all users / bots who are *already* subscribed to the guild. Is there any such event to let your bot know when it's been added to a guild?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes there is and you can view it in the client events https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client . A simple example to update an array of guilds using the event:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

let guildArray = client.guilds.array();

//joined a server
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log("Joined a new guild: " + guild.name);
    //Your other stuff like adding to guildArray
})

//removed from a server
client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    console.log("Left a guild: " + guild.name);
    //remove from guildArray
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I was confused. I thought those events were only when a new guild was actually created or deleted, not when the bot was merely added / removed from it.

Comment: Under what conditions is `guildDelete` fired?  If the bot is having a connectivity issue will it get fired?  Or is it only when the bot is actually removed by a user?

Comment: I sometimes run into this issue when some guilds are having an outage, it'd fire the guildDelete event, to avoid that I recommend using `guild.available` first before running anything in that event

Comment: @syntle where is the docs for guild.available? cant seem to find it, im trying to lighten the single sqlite file my bot has by deleting guild specific user data a month after the bot has been kicked and hasnt been invited again

Comment: @MrWinson https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=available